# EntityObject to XML and back to Object? (via DataTable if capable)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

***EDIT 2***

I am updating the question again to more simply explain what I need.
I need to take any EntityObject in my application, convert it to XML, which can be reconverted back to AN object later that can be queried or used in a DataSource.  I cannot reconvert to the original EntityObject because the structure of that object may have changed.  Is this doable?

***Original Question below***

Let's assume for a second that I am required by someone higher up than me (because I am) to take an EntityObject and convert it to a DataTable.  The example I was sent on how to do it is from 2006 and uses a custom class (which my boss thought was built into .Net) and it doesn't work anyway.

Is there a way to do this without writing my own custom class?  Something as simple as "new DataTable(myEntityObject)" would be amazing.  I'm guessing no though.

***EDIT***
I have changed the question because I was given the criteria wrong. Mainly we want our EntityObject to be XML so it can be stored in a database and reconstructed later.  Can that be done via Serialization?

Comment: You want to crate a dataTable from one Entity? One row in the table?

Comment: Yep.  Please just don't ask why.

Comment: I dont think there is such a function in the framework

Comment: Can you put some example? DataTable is table, where else entityObject is one row, how and what you want to achieve is little unclear.

Comment: Why do you want to store entity as XML? You can simply save it with EF.

Comment: @Ladislav : It's to have previous versions of changed data.  Kind of a mix of a Version Control System and a Log of Changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your updated question:
Use the `XmlSerializer`

```
public XElement XmlSerialize(object o)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, o);
                return XElement.Parse(sw.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Once I do this, can I rebuild that data into a DataTable?  The reason I won't go back to the EntityObject is that it might have changed since it was serialized.

Comment: You would have to parse the XML yourself onto a DataTable

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such built-in method / class. You must write your own conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a converter class for that, something like this:

```
public DataRow ToDataRow<T>(T entity)
public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
```